# Passing parameter as argument in onChange event?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a Javascript function during the `onchange` event.

html code:

```
<select name="model" id="model" onchange="demo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="100">Add New Model</option>
</select>
```

Javascript function:

```
function demo(a){
    alert(a);
}
```

but it doesn't show the alert box when I change value of the drop down. Why is it not working?

Fiddle showing the problem: [jsfiddle.net/kirtishatam/Gfzz7/1](http://jsfiddle.net/kirtishatam/Gfzz7/1)

Comment: Works just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VwZXQ/** ?

Comment: Why not just `this.value`? Note that in IE, navigating with the cursor keys fires a change event on each selection of an option.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kirtishatam/Gfzz7/1/ please check this link it not get proper output.what is wrong in that?

Comment: Have you disabled the pop-up box from showing up in your browser? Try exiting and restarting your browser.

Comment: @user3627152: Your fiddle works just fine. On the left pane of the fiddle, change "onload" to "wrap in body". Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Gfzz7/2/

Comment: thanks buddy actully i'm first time used fiddler.once again thanks to your help.